# Typescript 3 and array type nodes

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I recently updated from `typescript@2.9.x` to `typescript@3.0.3` and now i got errors in my transpiler program. You can find the sourcecode at [Github](https://github.com/wartoshika/qhun-transpiler/tree/typescript3).

The transpiler uses the typescript API with `ts.createProgram(...)` and the `program.getTypeChecker()` to check the actual type of the current node. You can see the transpiling setup in `src/compiler/Compiler.ts`.

My tests still work but array type tests stoped working. Here is the [Travis CI link](https://travis-ci.org/wartoshika/qhun-transpiler/builds/423300852) do view the test output.

My guess is that the `Types.isArray()` function in `src/transpiler/Types.ts` return the wrong boolean. Before `typescript@3` this function received syntax kind elements `ts.SyntaxKind.ArrayType` and `ts.SyntaxKind.TupleType`. When i debug my tests with an array type code like:

```
const testArray: number[] = [1,2,3,4]
const secondIndex: number = testArray[2];
```

The `Types.isArray()` will receive a node with a syntax kind of `ts.SyntaxKind.TypeLiteral`.

Typescript has modified the tuple type element to enable generics. Is this the `TypeLiteral`? This breaking changes may or may not affect my code.

If there are any additional questions, please ask, i will try to update this post.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out, that it is possible to get the type of the variable via it's symbol.
When testing a variable, it must be declared somewhere. This declaration should have a type on it and this type can be used to detect if this is an array or tuple type.

I refactored the `isArray(...)` function to reflect the variable declaration type. This is the new function:

```
public static isArray(node: ts.Node, typeChecker: ts.TypeChecker): boolean {

    // get the node type
    const type = typeChecker.getTypeAtLocation(node);
    const nodeType = typeChecker.typeToTypeNode(type);
    const symbol = typeChecker.getSymbolAtLocation(node);

    let typeLiteralArrayTypes: ts.SyntaxKind[];

    // at typescript >= 3 array types can be type literals
    if (symbol && symbol.declarations && nodeType.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.TypeLiteral) {

        typeLiteralArrayTypes = symbol.declarations.map(dec => {
            return (dec as any).type.kind;
        });
    }

    // make the test
    return nodeType
        // is an array literal
        && ts.isArrayLiteralExpression(node)
        // is a typescript 3 type literal
        || (typeLiteralArrayTypes
            && typeLiteralArrayTypes.every(typeLiteral => typeLiteral === ts.SyntaxKind.ArrayType || typeLiteral === ts.SyntaxKind.TupleType)
        )
        // normal types (typescript < 3)
        || (nodeType.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.ArrayType || nodeType.kind === ts.SyntaxKind.TupleType);
}
```

I am sure that this is not a solution, but this change satisfied my test cases. If you have a better solution please share it!